# what is the condition of using cross entropy in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

I want to  ask  when I calculate the cross entropy of the two distributions P and Q, should I ensure that `sum(P) = sum(Q) = 1` ?

Thanks

Comment: P and Q are probability distributions, so isn't their sum across the probability space equals to 1 automatically? So you don't need to ensure everything.

Comment: if the sum of distributions not equal to 1,  such as P=[0.1 0.3 0.6 0.8 0.9], Q is the output of nets (don't through softmax), can I use cross entropy directly?